Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTVideo" was not found in the UIManager
Error:
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTVideo" was not found in the UIManager.
using react-native-video(last version)
react-native version >0.60
react-native cli**(NOT EXPO)**
ios
const videoUrl = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
<Video source={{ uri: videoUrl }} style={vstyles.video} />

const vstyles = StyleSheet.create({
  video: {
    width: '20%',
    height: moderateScale(300),
    marginTop: moderateScale(10),
    borderRadius: moderateScale(8),
  },
});

reinstalling pods doesn`t work

This question is similar to: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Worked for me:
Update react-native version from "0.73.6" to "0.75.3"
run command "pod update hermes-engine --no-repo-update" in ios folder
Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78997452

Go to your terminal and enter the following command
For iOS
$   cd ios && pod install && cd ..

This will build all dependencies for the iOS devices, next you will need to go to Xcode and build the application again.
For Anrdoid
You will need to create a new development build.
